# Change event ID when writing to Windows Event Log with Log4jna

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, logging, log4jna

I am using [Log4jna](https://github.com/dblock/log4jna) to write logs to the Window Event Log. When I run my web application it automatically generates an Event ID.

Can I change the default event ID?